# Conver the Equation $r=a \sin x+b\cos x$ into Cartesian Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Hello :)) Wanted to convert the equation $r=a \sin x+b\cos x$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Knowing that $x = r \cos x$ and $y= = r \sin x$, I can make $x = (a \sin x + b \cos x) \cos x$. But this is kinda a dead end because I can't simplify this further. Also, knowing that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y ^2}$, I can make $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}= a \sin x + b \cos x$. This also seems like a dead end...so, any suggestions?

Comment: "$x = r \cos x$"  Ouch!  Pick a single meaning for $x$ and stick with it.

Comment: Did you mean $r=a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta$?

Comment: From $$x = r \cos \theta  \text{,}  $$ we have $$\frac{a}{r} x = \frac{a}{r} r \cos \theta = a \cos \theta  \text{...}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant to write $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. To have an equation in Cartesian form, you just want all of the variables to be in terms of $x$ and $y$.

So,

\begin{align*}
r=a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta&\implies r^2=ar\sin\theta+br\cos\theta&\text{multiplying both sides by }r\\
&\implies x^2+y^2=ay+bx
\end{align*}

From here, you can try to simplify write it in a form you would like, but as it stands, the last line is in Cartesian form.

Comment: Yes $\theta$ would have been a better choice

Answer (score 0):

If you need to solve fpr $x$ you can easily divide both side by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Then, we have:
$$\frac{r}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)$$
Let:
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$
We have:
$$\sin(x+\theta)=\frac{r}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yes I can take it from here :D

Comment: @Katto: if this answer has been useful,llet me know smashing thta +1 button. Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't have enough reputation to do that :(